# Proportional Hazards for Interval2 censored data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, hazard

I am trying to get proportional hazards for the survival object.

```
survobj1_2 <- Surv(time = as.numeric(set_1_2$int_1), time2 = as.numeric(set_1_2$int_2),
                   type = 'interval2')
```

I have tried using coxph() but it does not deal with interval censored data. I there any way around it?

I would also like to know if there is a way around for graphical diagnostics as well, similar to ggcoxzph(), which produces graphs (scaled schoenfeld residuals against transformed time)for each covariate?